# Creating an executable process that identifies which .txt files in a folder include certain text

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

My operating system is Windows 10.

I have a folder containing one to many .txt files. Within each file are lines formatted as the following:

> 2016-12-07 14:08:43  7.7 b=123 r=890

I am looking to create a reproducible process that I can execute that will look through all the files in the folder and provide me with the filenames in a .txt file of all the files that contain `6.7` and a date greater than seven days ago.

Example scenario:

File1 contains: `2016-12-07 14:08:43  7.7 b=123 r=890`

File2 contains: `2017-01-24 14:08:43  7.7 b=123 r=890`

File3 contains: `2017-01-23 14:08:43  6.7 b=123 r=890`

I execute the process and I receive a .txt file containg: `File3`

I don't know if this can be done using command line, PowerShell, or if full development efforts are needed to accomplish this task.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on JosefZ's original answer, I find the following answer more complete.

Include the following within a PowerShell file:

```
$filespath = "\\sampledirectory\log\"
$outputfilename = "\\sampledirectory\log\results.txt"

########## file creation step
Get-ChildItem -Path $filespath *.txt -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $aux=$_
        Get-Content "$aux" | 
            ForEach-Object {
                if ($_ -match '6\.7')
                {
                    if ( [datetime] $_.Substring(0,19) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))
                    {
                        $aux.FullName | Out-File $outputfilename -append
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following PowerShell script

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $aux=$_
        Get-Content "$aux" | 
            ForEach-Object {
                if ($_ -match '6\.7') {
                    if ( [datetime] $_.Substring(0,19) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) {
                        $aux.FullName
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

or equivalent oneliner

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $aux=$_; Get-Content "$aux" | ForEach-Object {if ($_ -match '6\.7') {if ( [datetime] $_.Substring(0,19) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) {$aux.FullName}}}}
```

**Basic explanation**:

- Get a list of `txt` files `Get-ChildItem` and `|` pipe result to next cmdlet
- *(piped)* for every particular file `ForEach-Object`
- save it to an auxiliary variable `$aux=$_` (note trailing `;` semicolon in the oneliner)
- and get it's content line by line `Get-Content` and `|` pipe result to next cmdlet
- *(piped)* for every particular line `ForEach-Object`
- test whether a line contains `6.7` string `if ($_ -match '6\.7')`
- and if so then test whether date (first 19 characters) matches given criteria `if ( [datetime] …`
- and if so then make public file name  `$aux.FullName`
- and close all opening `{`s using series of closing `}`s.

Comment: This script writes the name of the file to the PowerShell window for each occurrence of the defined search text. It does not create a new file containing this information. I'll have to look into how to write the PowerShell displayed results to file to get where I want to be. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @HappyCoding you can pipe output e.g. to [`Out-File` cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293996). Read again [David's comment](http://superuser.com/questions/1172387/creating-an-executable-process-that-identifies-which-txt-files-in-a-folder-incl/1172455?noredirect=1#comment1694476_1172387).